# Showing Windows media control asp.net c#.

Tags: c#, asp.net

Scenario: I am creating a web app where a user uploads videos and its path is stored in database.
I am showing data list that includes the videos and on item_command() event of that data list I am navigation to a new form (Webform2) where I am using Windows media player control to play that video.

The problem is: The windows media player control is not showing up in the form.

This is where I am adding the control to the page.

```
<div style="text-align: center; vertical-align: middle">
        <cc1:Media_Player_Control ID="Media_Player_Control1" runat="server" Height="299px" Width="542px" />
             <br />

</div>
```

Here I am assigning URL to the control

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        long vidid=Convert.ToInt64(Session["vid"]); //Getting id of the item that is clicked
        DataClasses1DataContext db = new DataClasses1DataContext();
        var vid = (from v in db.Videos
                   where v.videoId == vidid
                   select v.videoPath).FirstOrDefault();





        Media_Player_Control1.MovieURL = vid.ToString();


    }
```

Answer (score 0):

use this in your markup [example link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd564350%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

```
<OBJECT ID="Player" height="0" width="0"
CLASSID="CLSID:6BF52A52-394A-11d3-B153-00C04F79FAA6">
</OBJECT>
```