# Video is not playing in asp.net web page

Tags: asp.net

I downloaded a media player control from  the Net then added in my toolbox. Then I drag-and-dropped it to my web page but it's not working...

```
cc1:Media_Player_Control ID="Media_Player_Control1" runat="server" 
                MovieURL="./video/yaarian.wmv"
```

this is my code

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the path is correct 
e.g.

- remove ./ if video is located in the child folder named video
- or use absolute path e.g. /pages/video/yaarian.wmv

Comment: 1st time path was just like that which you are saying but that was working. so i changed the path style to try this may be it will work. but it didn't

Comment: "path was just like that ... but that was working." If it was _working_ then what is the problem?

Comment: So, what is the issue? is video file is in the video folder? Did you try to call wmv file directly in the browser (to test the path)?

Comment: yes video is in the video folder.  and i have checked by every method but issue is that video is not playing

Answer (score 0):

Check the [control registration tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5276533/how-to-register-custom-server-control-on-asp-net-page) and make sure you have the assembly loaded in your bin folder:

```
<%@ Register TagPrefix="cc1" Namespace="MyApp.Controls" Assembly="MyApp" %>
```

Then, try the following:

```
<cc1:Media_Player_Control ID="Media_Player_Control1" runat="server" 
                MovieURL="~/video/yaarian.wmv" runat="server" />
```

Comment: from where i can check assembly loaded or not?

Comment: <%@ Register assembly="Media-Player-ASP.NET-Control" namespace="Media_Player_ASP.NET_Control" tagprefix="cc1" %> its already written in my code

Comment: Try using an actual URL? http://forums.asp.net/t/1537737.aspx?relative+url+does+not+work+for+media+player+control+MovieURL+property

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23848131/showing-windows-media-control-asp-net-c